# How does one control the thrusters on a Hydra in GTA:SA on Android?

Tags: android, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

The UI provided for the Hydra seems to be the same as for Dodo, Shamal, etc (as far as movement is concerned). The thrusters seem to automatically switch between pointing backwards and downwards, perhaps based on speed, but it's not clear how. Is there a way to control them directly?

This also makes movement on ground hard, since the thrusters are pointing downwards.

Comment: Agreed. Dating girlfriends with the Hydra is annoyingly hard.

Comment: @Jonny How did that contribute at all?

And currently there is no way to control it from what I have researched. You only can on the Consoles/PC.

Comment: Well... in other, a bit related news, Rockstar released an update for GTA Vice City for iOS today - now supporting physical game controllers (that iPhones support since iOS 7). So we can hope for a similar update to GTA SA... maybe then we can control the hydra, if we have a physical controller. Oh I don't use Android for games.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately on Android & iOS there is no way to control this. This may come in the future as there has been a lot of criticism on the flight controls for mobile devices, but that is only speculation.

What i have done for other games is get a bluetooth controller connected to my device, but that is not compatible with all games, and i cant confirm it would be with SA, i have managed it with Vice City though.

Answer (score 0):

you can lean forwards, but only one you have a good altitude. For some reason, when the hydra faces downwards, it automatically moves the thrusters in the "move-the-hydra-forwards"position

Answer (score 0):

Hold the break and hold lean back. I just did it and it works. I just did this to hover over the boats to complete the Vertical Bird mission.

Answer (score -1):

Lean forwards while going up to go into flying mode. Brake and lean backwards to go into hover mode.